# Google Places Autocomplete Delegate not set

Tags: swift, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I am setting the delegate of the autocomplete view controller to the current class, which has an autocompleteviewcontrollerdelegate extension. This has has always worked in the past, but recently I am getting an error message printing out that says the delegate for the autocomplete controller is not set and I can confirm the delegate is no longer being called. I have the print(self) line to check that I am in fact setting the correct class to be the delegate. I have this exact same setup in another part of my app that is working fine. Any suggestions on how to debug this issue?

```
@objc func searchButton() {
            print(self)
            let acController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
            acController.delegate = self
            acController.autocompleteBounds = getBounds(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)
            // Specify a filter.
            //let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
            //filter.type = establishment
            //acController.autocompleteFilter = filter
            present(acController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my viewwillDisappear method I pop the view controller so that if the user navigated away from the page with the tab bar controller the next time they navigate to the page they will be on the main page. Whenever the autocomplete view controller was appearing the parent viewcontroller was getting popped off the stack and killing off the delegate.